# Excel VBA code to update the hide/unhide rows functions when a new row is added within the range wanted to be hidden

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a code as follows to hide a range of cells when an **activeX** checkbox is clicked:

**Version 1:**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

    Rows("14:30").Hidden = False

    Else

    Rows("14:30").Hidden = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then

    Rows("32:38").Hidden = False

    Else

    Rows("32:38").Hidden = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then

    Rows("40:54").Hidden = False

    Else

    Rows("40:54").Hidden = True

    End If

End Sub
```

**Version 2:**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    [14:30].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    [32:38].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox2

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

    [40:54].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox3

End Sub
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

Both **versions** work fine BUT the problem is that when a new row is added within the ranges specified, the row specifications obviously do not update as they are not variables.

**NOTE**: There are more than 3 ActiveX checkboxes. I've got about 19.

**QUESTION**

I know the ranges need to be put to an integer or a variable but I am only new to VBA and not even a programmer (studied a few programming applications in college 4 years ago so can read code a bit) so I have no idea how to do it. Currently working on automating an excel file at work and WOULD LOVE YOUR HELP PLEASEEEE! I have been struggling for days on this :(

Excel file looks like this:

[image: Clip1]

[image: Clip2]

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You will need something that vba can use to mark the ranges so that they can be set programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that Scott but sadly I do not know how to do it. I have tried researching so much my head hurts! Only new to VBA!

Comment: So tell us what we can use, maybe give a picture of the data.  We cannot help with the info you have given.

Comment: Added!. Hope that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically determine the starting row and end row for each section. This should work for the top *A - General* section.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim m1 As Variant, m2 As Variant

    m1 = Application.Match("A -*", Columns(1), 0)
    m2 = Application.Match("B -*", Columns(1), 0)

    If IsError(m1) Or IsError(m2) Then Exit Sub

    With Range(Cells(m1 + 1, "A"), Cells(m2 - 1, "A"))
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you have 19 checkboxes then create a common sub which takes two arguments such as "A - *" and "B - *" and call that from each of the click handlers.

Comment: Oh WOW!. Amazing!! Thanks so much. It worked!!! However, I did not understand what I should do with the rest of the 18 checkboxes? Do i need to copy and past that code again for each one but instead changing the "B - *" and "C - *" respectively. Or, is there a way to put a loop or something for that, say A to X, and then just call one thing within the click functions for each checkbox?